# Segue to different UITableViewControllers from a single UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a simple application with a `UICollectionViewController` that has been designed in `Storyboard`. There is a single cell (`UICollectionViewCell`) that I've designed in the `UICollectionViewController` because it is dynamic.

My `UICollectionViewController` is called `Videos` and I have a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` called `VideosCell` where I have an `IBOutlet` from `Storyboard` to a `UILabel`. `Videos` is populated using a `NSArray` of Languages. Within `Storyboard`, I also have 2 `UITableViewControllers`; one called `VideosFromVideoTab` and another called `English Topics`. I have set up a `segue` from the `VideosCell` in `Storyboard` to the `LanguagesFromVideos` and then in `prepareForSegue`, I have the following:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.videosTabCollectionView indexPathForCell:sender];

    [self.videosTabCollectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    VideosTabCollectionCell *videosTabCell = (VideosTabCollectionCell *)[self.videosTabCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"languagesFromVideoSegue"])
    {

        if ([videosTabCell.videosTabCellLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Chinese\n汉语"])
        {
            LanguageFromVideoTabTableViewController *lfvtvc = (LanguageFromVideoTabTableViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
            NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Chinese Videos" ofType:@"txt"];
            NSString *testString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
            NSArray *listOfVideos = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
            NSMutableArray *availableVideosToPass = [listOfVideos mutableCopy];

            NSString *theSelectedLanguage = @"Chinese - 汉语";

            [lfvtvc setAvailableVideos:availableVideosToPass];
            [lfvtvc setSelectedLanguage:theSelectedLanguage];

        }
Etc
```

So I am checking this `segue identifier` and then checking the language of the label to see what happens. That works very well.

However, in my head, for the English language, instead of going to `VideosFromVideoTab`, it's supposed to go to the `English Topic UITableViewController`, so I thought I could set up another `segue` with a different `identifier` and then just check that in the `prepareForSegue`.

**Issue**

However, in `Storyboard`, whenever I set another `segue` from the `VideosCell`, it keeps only one. So if I had a `segue` from the `VideosCell` to the `VideosFromVideosTab` `UITableViewController`, it keeps that, but if I set another `segue` from the `VideosCell` to the `English Topic UITableViewController`, it removes the first segue.

In a separate area of the app, I have a `segue` from a single `UITableViewCell` to two different `UITableViewControllers`. Am I missing something obvious that's stopping me from doing this from the `UICollectionViewCell`?

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have to use push programmatically.

```
FirstViewController * controller = (FirstViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstView"];

[controller setAvailableVideos:availableVideosToPass];
[controller setSelectedLanguage:theSelectedLanguage];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

And for second

```
SecondViewController * controller = (SecondViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

In such way you could send to number of ViewControllers depend on selected cell.

Comment: Thanks @Nazir - is that in the prepareForSegue or didSelectItemAtIndexPath?

Comment: You have to use it where you control of cell selection `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` - also it will be easy for you to prepare data. And one important comment - remove segue from storyboard it will duplicate and you will get crash or warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more than one segue from the cell, you have to set segues from ViewController to ViewController with different ID.

Then catch Cell select and in use

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"id1" sender:self];
```

or

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"id2" sender:self];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - so I did the segue in Storyboard from VC to VC instead of the cell and in didSelectItemAtIndexPath, I checked the cell and then performed segue depending on the cell, but it crashes with unrecognised selector on this line in prepareForSegue:     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.videosTabCollectionView indexPathForCell:sender]; - my app is completely working except the English - if there's a way I can do this in Storyboard from the cell, it'll be so much easier because then in prepareForSegue, I can prepare what needs to be passed, etc, like the other languages.